# How do I install the AMD Raidxpert 2 driver?

Tags: drivers

I have the Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS AMD64 liveCD iso installed on a USB drive

I'm booting from a raid array made with the raidxpert 2 tool included with my motherboard and I need the driver for it.

My drives don't show up at all without the right driver.

Specs:

- mobo: Gigabyte X470 AORUS ULTRA GAMING
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600x
- RAM: HyperX Fury DDR4 2666MHz 2x8GB

Comment: According to the manual you should have a cd with the driver on it (named `RAIDXpert{DIGITS}.bin`) Would that not be more ideal? :)

Comment: Can you not just avoid the hardware RAID config, and instead use software RAID with `mdadm`? Or are you doing dual boot and need to access the existing hardware RAID from Linux?

Comment: Unfortunately, can't find any raidxpert{DIGITS}.bin on that cd. Thanks for the sugestion.

Comment: By searching for dd-rcraid-Ubuntu116-4.4.0-31 on the internett, I found what I was looking for, Thank you for your help. https://support.amd.com/en-us/download/chipset?os=Linux+x86_64

Comment: damn I had that url too but thought it was not what you needed :D Make an answer if you get it working so others do not have to go through the same hoops as you had to :)

Comment: Yes, I will, but I'm new to linux and probably won't get it to work before tomorrow. Now that I have the files required, I will probably be able to figure the rest out by myself or just search the web.

Comment: No, I'm stuck. I have a bunch of strange files and I am supposed to put them in a dd directory. I don't know how to do that, I have read a couple of guides, but I still don't get it.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and eliminate the extraneously long unrelated pieces.

Comment: Try this build: https://github.com/thopiekar/rcraid-dkms

Answer (score -2):

Files are here: [amd support](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/chipset?os=Linux%20x86_64)

(http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/chipset?os=Linux%20x86_64)

Comment: The above link doesn't work. The best bet is to try this homebrew build: https://github.com/thopiekar/rcraid-dkms